# Nuget nuspec not working with wildcard

Tags: c#, xml, package, nuget

I'm building a nuget package and all is well until I try to use the wildcard to import all dll's in a folder.

This works perfectly

```
<file src="KL.Ocr.Tesseract/x86/liblept172.dll" target="content\x86"/>
```

however this does nothing

```
<file src="KL.Ocr.Tesseract/x86/*.dll" target="content\x86"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated (and I am intentionally placing the dll's in content instead of lib because thats where they need to be)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
 <metadata>
 <id>asdf</id>
 <version>1.0.0.0</version>
 <title>asdf</title>
 <authors>asdf</authors>
 <owners>asdf</owners>
 <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
 <description>asdf </description>
 <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
 <tags>asdf</tags>
 <frameworkAssemblies>
 </frameworkAssemblies>
 <dependencies>

 </dependencies>
</metadata>
<files>
<file src="KL.Pas.Ocr.targets" target="build"/>

<file src="KL.Ocr.Pas.Host/bin/Debug/KL.Ocr.Pas.Host.dll" target="lib/net45"  />
<file src="KL.Ocr.Pas.Host/bin/Debug/KL.Ocr.Pas.Worker.exe" target="lib/net45"  />
<file src="KL.Ocr.Pas.Host/bin/Debug/KL.Pas.Ocr.Contracts.dll" target="lib/net45"  />
<file src="KL.Ocr.Pas.Host/bin/Debug/KL.Ocr.Tesseract.dll" target="lib/net45"  />
<file src="KL.Ocr.Pas.Host/bin/Debug/Tesseract.dll" target="lib/net45"  />

<file src="KL.Ocr.Tesseract/x64/*.dll" target="build\x64"/>    
<file src="KL.Ocr.Tesseract/x86/*.dll" target="build\x86"/>    
<file src="KL.Ocr.Tesseract/tessdata/*.*" target="build\tessdata"/>
</files>
</package>
```

Comment: Can you post your .nuspec file?

Comment: @MattWard I have posted it

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you are generating the NuGet package on Windows.

If you switch to using backslash instead of forward slashes then it will work.

```
<file src="KL.Ocr.Tesseract\x64\*.dll" target="build\x64"/>
```

The above works fine. Using forward slashes does not seem to work.

Comment: What version of NuGet are you using? The above works fine for me with NuGet v2 and NuGet 3.4.4 on Windows.

Comment: Switching forward slashes to backward worked for me in NuGet 3.5.0 (custom build for OctoPack).